# What is the period between brahmachari ashram and grihasti ashram called?

Tags: moksha, purushartha, ashram

What would you call a pass out in which ashram he is ?

Comment: A pass out , from a Vedic Gurukula , takes part in a ceremony known as Samavartana , (something like convocation ceremony in modern times)..From then on , he is known as **Snataka**, till he transits into Grihasthashrama

Comment: Are there any specific rules/religious practises for a Snataka?@Athrey